# Retrofit: вместо ошибки хочу null

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, gson

Ситуация следующая:
получаю данные через Ретрофит.
в модели ответа есть поле, которое я жду как `Int?` (поле необязательное).
если в ответе будет, например, Double, то весь запрос упадет с ошибкой

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected an int but was 1.23 at line 3 column 19 path $[0].userId
```

а мне хочется, чтобы в таком случае в поле засеталось просто `null`
как это можно сделать?

Comment: Кажется тут только если свой десериализатор писать. Однако выглядит задача так, что лучше бы на бэке пофиксить. Ну а если там - никак и такой случай единственный - то, возможно, стоит просто в Double парсить и программно после получения данных проверять целое ли число в Double пришло.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а что вы думаете насчет идеи, чтобы сетевая модель всегда принимала String, а уже потом перегонять поля в domain-модели в нужные Int, Double, Date и тд. если не получается - null. и там уже смотреть "допустим ли null или нет"

Comment: Можно и так, хотя кажется, что это усложнение и дополнение предложенного варианта парсинга в Double с проверкой на наличие дробной части. Маппинг данных да, многие проблемы решит, однако если вы вообще все поля сделаете строковыми, то потеряете значительную часть удобства пользования либами для парсинга JSON. По идее надо бэк теребить чтобы они нормальные данные выдавали. Если это нельзя - лучше ограничиться обработкой редких случаев. Возможно вам подойдёт что-то типа парсинга в Double и конвертацией в Int при мапинге как-то так: `doubleValue.toInt()`.

Answer (score -2):

оберните свой код в try-catch,  в  catch опишите то что вы хотите получить

```
 working code //
    int result=0;
    try (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    result =  0 ;//  или -9999999 
    }
```

null возвращать плохая идея, можно вернуть то что вряд ли будет результатом, например огромное отрицательное число.